# Adding sign in to an AngularJS SPA error: Application 'XXX' is not supported for this API version

Tags: azure-active-directory

I am developing a simple web page and I'm trying to configure sign in for both personal and business accounts. I've followed the entire tutorial posted here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-v2-devquickstarts-angular-dotnet/

After I try to sign in with my account, I get redirected to an error page saying:
AADSTS70001: Application 'XXX' is not supported for this API version. 
I've tried creating the application with both my personal and my corporate credentials, with no luck. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There's two potential scenarios going on here.

1. Your app is registered as a v1 but you are trying to access it via the v2 endpoint.
2. Your app is registered as a v2 but you are trying to access it via the v1 endpoint.

**To address #1**, make sure that you create the app via the App Registration Portal: https://apps.dev.microsoft.com

Log in to that portal and make sure your app shows up there. If it doesn't, then your app is most likely a v1 app. You'll need to create a new app in this portal and use that one instead.

**To address #2**, make sure that you are using the experimental version of ADAL.js. You can tell it's the right version by confirming that the URL when you try to sign in looks like this

login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/**v2.0**/authorize?client_id=...

If the v2.0 is missing, you're using the wrong version of ADAL.js